# abstract optimization problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, optimization

Suppose we have general optimization problem $f(x)\rightarrow min$, where x is an element of some algebraic structure (e.g. x is rotation matrix and is an element of SO(3)).

There are plenty of ways to parametrize x or algorithms which can work with quaternions or other objects, but **what are the general optimization methods that work directly with elements of some abstract algebraic structure?**